# My instance doesn't fetch me the table that I want

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I am trying to attach an object full of information from the MYSQL DB, but the outcome isn't what I am expecting.

Controller -

```
public function index()
{
    $location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    return view('location')->with('locations', $location);
}
```

Model -

```
class Location extends Model
{
    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

Result -

```
  Builder {#486 ▼
  #query: Builder {#485 ▶}
  #model: Location {#484 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:12 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Change this
    $location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

To 

    $location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem but how can I upvote your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I am posting from my mobile so could format the code . To accept answer you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using **$location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');** it is a instance of **Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder**. 
For get all records you must use

```
$locations = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

It is return instance of **\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection**
For get **Limited** records you must use

```
$limit = 20; // or custom
$limitedLocations = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit($limit)->get();
```

For get single data use

```
$location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

It is return **null** or instance of model **Location**

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

To

```
$location = Location::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```